# How to see source line numbers Concat and Minifying JS in Grunt.js

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, group-concat, grunt-contrib-uglify

I use [Concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) and [Uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) tasks for Grunt.js. I get one minified js-file combined of multiple *.js after their uglification. That works fine. If I get error, the browser uses source map to view the error line number in dev file (one of that multiple files).

But if I use `console.log('...')` I see the line number from the result (uglified and combined file), not the dev one.

How can I make console to show me the dev file line number? Thanks.

Comment: Nope! Only use concat and uglify for production, never for development. The point of the these tasks is to reduce the amount of whitespace and unnecessary junk so it loads faster on the internet. You want to test using the original files during development.

Comment: @ninty9notout ok, so the only way I see is to use multiple js with sourcemaps and concat them for internet usage after development.